# Evo Pdf style rendering issue for input button

Tags: evopdf

```
<style>
 input[type="submit"]{background-color: red;}
 .myButton{background-color: red;}
</style>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton">
```

The input button is not getting the styling.

Comment: this would work, maybe you have another class overriding it?

Comment: @XanderLuciano : http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/PDF_Forms/Auto_Create_PDF_Forms.aspx I tried adding in this page HTML form and tried generating the PDF. The pdf is not getting the style. Can you please write for me so that it works

Answer (score 0):

When converting HTML forms to interactive PDF forms the submit buttons use a standard style for PDF forms, they cannot use all styles you define in HTML document